# The loading message is not updated when the process starts

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, event-dispatch-thread

I want to display a "loading message" when a process is started and I want to change the message when the process is finished. I tried to update the text from a `JLabel` before and after the thread with the process is started but the problem is that on the frame appears only the last update.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyClass extends JFrame {
    private JLabel loading;
    private JButton jButton;
    private JPanel jPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass();
    }

    MyClass() {
        jPanel = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        loading = new JLabel("");
        loading.setVisible(true);

        jButton = new JButton("Click me!");
        addActionToJButon();

        setSize(300, 300);
        jPanel.add(jButton);
        jPanel.add(loading);

        add(jPanel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addActionToJButon() {
        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loading.setText("Loading....");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) {
                        System.out.println(i);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            loading.setText("Done!");
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

I was expecting to appear the label "Loading..." once what the process is started and the message "Done" when the process is finished but I can't find out why on the frame appears the label with the message "Done!".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java swing graphics not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52731997/java-swing-graphics-not-updating)

Comment: When you start a thread, you just do that: starting a thread, that will execute concurrently. So your `loading.setText("Done!");` executes immediately after you have **started** the thread. Not when the thread has **finished** executing. Use a SwingWorker. Or update the label from inside the thread, after the loop, wrapped in a SwingUtilities.invokeLater() call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to  JB Nizet advices I used SwingWorker and the code is working now.

Here is the correct code:

```
package view;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class MyClass extends JFrame {
    private JLabel loading;
    private JButton jButton;
    private JPanel jPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass();
    }

    MyClass() {
        jPanel = new JPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        loading = new JLabel("");
        loading.setVisible(true);

        jButton = new JButton("Click me!");
        addActionToJButon();

        setSize(300, 300);
        jPanel.add(jButton);
        jPanel.add(loading);

        add(jPanel);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addActionToJButon() {
        jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                loading.setText("Loading....");

                swingWorker();
            }
        });
    }

    private void swingWorker() {
        SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker<String, String>() {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground() throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                return "Done";
            }

            protected void done() {
                try {
                    String finished =  get();
                    loading.setText(finished);
                } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        worker.execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Because you are doing your "loading" within a thread, and you are setting your loading text outside the thread, you immediately set loading to "Done!" when you begin loading.  What you want to do is set loading within your run() function like this:

```
private void addActionToJButon() {
    jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                loading.setText("Loading....");
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i <= 1000000; i++) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                }
                loading.setText("Done!");
            }
        }).start();
        }   
    });
}
```

Comment: No, you can't access swing components from a thread other than the Swing event dispatch thread.

Comment: I just ran the code myself.  Go ahead and try it.  It works.

Comment: I just crossed the street with my eyes closed. And I'm still alive. Go ahead, it works.

Comment: What a constructive comment.  Thanks

Comment: My first comment was very constructive, and clearly explained what was wrong in your code, but you chose to disregard it. Just because something happens to work once doesn't mean it's correct or safe. You're violating the Swing thread rules, and I explained why. My comment under the question also explains how to do it right.